# Srcset seems to not properly resize image while PageSpeed Insights test

Tags: pagespeed-insights, srcset, hubspot-cms

I have a [page](https://emobility-magazin.com/e-auto-foerderung/) run by Hubspot Blog and an image implementation with `srcset`, looking like this:

```
<img loading="lazy" src="
https://emobility-magazin.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Element%2023@300x.png?width=480&amp;name=Element%2023@300x.png" 
alt="Element 23@300x" width="480" style="width: 480px;" srcset="
https://emobility-magazin.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Element%2023@300x.png?width=240&amp;name=Element%2023@300x.png 240w, 
https://emobility-magazin.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Element%2023@300x.png?width=480&amp;name=Element%2023@300x.png 480w, 
https://emobility-magazin.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Element%2023@300x.png?width=720&amp;name=Element%2023@300x.png 720w, 
https://emobility-magazin.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Element%2023@300x.png?width=960&amp;name=Element%2023@300x.png 960w, 
https://emobility-magazin.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Element%2023@300x.png?width=1200&amp;name=Element%2023@300x.png 1200w, 
https://emobility-magazin.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Element%2023@300x.png?width=1440&amp;name=Element%2023@300x.png 1440w" 
sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw, 480px">
```

The issue: Google PageSpeed Insights test delivers as an opportunity `properly size images`, with a diagnozed problem with the image I mentioned above. It looks like the `srcset` doesn't work for PageSpeed Insights test and the image isn't resized properly.

[image]

Getting the test data directly through Page Speed Insights API the issue is diagnozed too, on the same way.

But, running the Chrome-own Lighthouse test outta Developer Tools (incognito mode), the issue isn't there - the image seems to be properly resized by `srcset`.

My question: is there something, what prevents correct resizing while testing by PageSpeed Insights test? Are there any issues in my srcset implementation? Or is this a kind of bug of PageSpeed Insights?

Answer (score 2):

So there's a couple of things going on here:

1. All your images are the same 6510x10194 images. So the audit is correct to highlight the image as improperly sized. Is the `width` param supposed to result in different size images being returned?
2. I'm not sure why it's not failing the audit on desktop. I can repeat what you see but to me it should be failing there too. So PSI looks more correct here.
3. Your `sizes` attribute looks incomplete to me. Maybe that's what's throwing off the browser for point 2?

When I run it through https://ausi.github.io/respimagelint/ it gives the following output:

> **W descriptor doesn’t match the image size**
> Descriptor `240w` doesn’t match the image size of 6510x10194 from …/Element%2023@300x.png?width=240….
>
> Descriptor `480w` doesn’t match the image size of 6510x10194 from …/Element%2023@300x.png?width=480….
>
> Descriptor `720w` doesn’t match the image size of 6510x10194 from …/Element%2023@300x.png?width=720….
>
> Descriptor `960w` doesn’t match the image size of 6510x10194 from …/Element%2023@300x.png?width=960….
>
> Descriptor `1200w` doesn’t match the image size of 6510x10194 from …/Element%2023@300x.png?width=1200….
>
> Descriptor `1440w` doesn’t match the image size of 6510x10194 from …/Element%2023@300x.png?width=1440….
>
> A fitting image source should be available for all screen sizes
> At a viewport of 1280×720 the image was displayed 480 pixels wide, but the closest provided image has a width of 6510 which is 93% (66 megapixels) off. The affected viewports are 300×169–3000×4000.
>
> Try using the following image sizes in `<img srcset="…">` instead:
> 260×407, 480×752, 760×1190, 960×1503
>
> Loading a large image and display it much smaller should be avoided to save bandwidth. Loading a small image and display it much larger should be avoided to prevent pixelated artifacts.
>
> **The `sizes` attribute has to match the width of the image**
>
> The size of the image doesn’t match the `sizes` attribute `(max-width: 480px) 100vw, 480px`. At a viewport of 1000x563 the image was 424 pixels wide instead of the specified 480 (-12% difference). The affected viewports are 300x169-480x640, 780x439-940x1253, 1000x563-1020x1360.
>
> Try using `sizes="(min-width: 1220px) 480px, (min-width: 1000px) calc(28vw + 144px), (min-width: 780px) calc(50vw - 36px), (min-width: 560px) 480px, calc(91.67vw - 15px)"` instead.
>
> The `sizes` attribute is a hint for browsers which should tell them how large the image will be displayed. If it doesn’t match the real size, browsers cannot select the correct image source.