# PageSpeed Insights reports "Properly size images" even if I use srcset/sizes

Tags: html, mobile, pagespeed-insights, srcset

I'm trying to improve PageSpeed insights score. PageSpeed reports "Properly size images" even if I use srcset/sizes (on mobile).

[PageSpeed test results](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-authland-com/5ppv9uguzq?form_factor=mobile)

Am I doing something wrong?

I tried to change the sizes attribute but Chrome always loads a 600px wide image for mobile.

I ran it through https://ausi.github.io/respimagelint ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74144429/22428348)) and it passes all tests.

Comment: I find this frustrating because you are providing different sizes using srcset, then the browser is picking the size that it wants to show.  A device with x2 or x3 pixel density will likely pick a larger size, but that's hardly your fault.  Since you probably want the same image to display properly on desktop it's not like you have the option to limit it to very small sizes. In short, I have the same problem and I don't know of any sensible solution.